# yii2 how to use response sendFile() with pjax

Tags: yii2, response, sendfile

I have observed that when I execute the function:

`Yii::$app->request->sendFile()` within a row with a gridView, instead of launching the file, it shows it embedded in the `HTML`.

Then if I remove the `Pjax::begin()` and `Pjax::end()` borders that enclose the GridView, Then download works.

How can I work with both functionalities without losing one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was discussed at Yii2 the solution for now is to use this method:

```
<?php Pjax::begin([
    'id' => 'list',
    'linkSelector' => '#list a:not([data-pjax=0])'
 ]); ?>
<a href="#" id="customListener" data-pjax="0">custom js or simple link to your action with download</a>
<a href="some/link">pjax link</a>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

It looks like this feature may be included in future releases.

Comment: You don't have to explicitly define `linkSelector` for `data-pjax="0"` to work. It already works that way so just adding that to link is enough.